# Why is Azure WebSite giving null ConnectionStrings?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I am working on an ASP.Net WebForms solution that i have uploaded to Azure and is working fine  except for the fact that whenever i try to acquire connectiong string either via `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` or `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` as outlined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/07/17/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work.aspx)

Azure config:
[image]

Any ideas? I'm pretty desperate now.

Answer (score 1):

ConnectionStrings in Azure Management portal replace already defined connectionstrings in Web.Config at runtime. They do not physically override the web.config connectionstrings.

If no corresponding connectionstring is available in web.config, with the same name as mentioned in the azure management portal, then it will not be replaced at runtime.

So please make sure you have some dummy connectionstrings in web.config with same names as of the connectionstrings mentioned in azure portal. I think that will solve your access problems.

Comment: I have two connection strings with the same names on my local web.config file but that file is not uploaded to the Azure Website when i hit publish (VS 2013) and trying to upload it via FTP seems unfortunately to fail. How can i tell VS to upload the Web.Config file as well? - Setting Copy Always on the Web.config yields build errors

Comment: When you publish from VS, in FTP mode, in the third tab i.e., on settings, you can specify delete all files prior to publish. That will delete all files in old deployment and re-deploy new files using FTP. also do add <clear/> in the <connectionstrings> node of web.config, before <add/>. That will make sure to remove all old references of connectionstrings.

Comment: Is it necessary for me to deploy using FTP so the web.config file is uploaded? I am currently using the auto-generated publish profile for my website

Comment: I switched over to a FTP profile and it still won't upload the Web.Config file

Comment: Interesting, can you try the same code with another fresh instance of AxureWebsite? and see if you are able to publish the web.config there? Also when you generate the preview of deployment can you check if Web.config is missing from there?

Comment: I have another webiste on Azure (Asp.Net MVC5, VS 2013 project) that does deploy the Web.config file normally, but i got a workaround: The FTP error was due to Win8 having a slight bug on SSL. I've uploaded a Web.config file manually and have met some unknown error i have yet to be able to discern.